# JS Plugin Speeds Up After Visiting Diff. Tab in Firefox

Tags: jquery, gallery, slideshow, settimeout

I know this topic has been covered both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112671/settimeout-speeds-up-with-multiple-tabs) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618986/jquery-javascript-my-recursive-settimeout-function-speeds-up-when-tab-becomes-i), but I'm afraid I still haven't been able to figure out the exact source of the issue that's causing my SlideShow (using [FadeGallery](http://pastebin.com/BxN8vbAt)) to queue the animations while I'm on another tab and then speed through the slides upon my return on Firefox. Any chance someone out there can help me tackle the issue?

I am pretty terrible with JS and really have no place even attempting to figure this out on my own... but, I have been, to no avail. So, any help would be appreciated. Based on the previous posts, it seems to either be something with `setTimeout`, `.queue` or `$(window).focus`, but I'm just not entirely sure what to do to change it.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function(){
    initSlideshow();
});

// slideshow init
function initSlideshow(){
    jQuery('div.slide-show').fadeGallery({
        pauseOnHover:true,
        autoRotation:true,
        switchTime:7000        //ms
    });
};


// slideshow plugin
jQuery.fn.fadeGallery = function(_options){
    var _options = jQuery.extend({
        slideElements:'ul.slide > li',
        pagerGener: true,
        pagerHold: 'div.switcher',
        pagerLinks:'div.switcher li',
        btnNext:'a.btn-next',
        btnPrev:'a.btn-prev',
        btnPlayPause:'a.play-pause',
        btnPlay:'a.play',
        btnPause:'a.pause',
        pausedClass:'paused',
        disabledClass: 'disabled',
        playClass:'playing',
        activeClass:'active',
        currentNum:false,
        allNum:false,
        startSlide:null,
        noCircle:false,
        caption:'ul.caption > li',
        pauseOnHover:true,
        autoRotation:false,
        autoHeight:false,
        onChange:false,
        switchTime:3000,
        duration:650,
        event:'click'
    },_options);

    return this.each(function(){
        // gallery options
        var _this = jQuery(this);
        var _slides = jQuery(_options.slideElements, _this);
        var _btnPrev = jQuery(_options.btnPrev, _this);
        var _btnNext = jQuery(_options.btnNext, _this);
        var _btnPlayPause = jQuery(_options.btnPlayPause, _this);
        var _btnPause = jQuery(_options.btnPause, _this);
        var _btnPlay = jQuery(_options.btnPlay, _this);
        var _pauseOnHover = _options.pauseOnHover;
        var _autoRotation = _options.autoRotation;
        var _activeClass = _options.activeClass;
        var _disabledClass = _options.disabledClass;
        var _pausedClass = _options.pausedClass;
        var _playClass = _options.playClass;
        var _autoHeight = _options.autoHeight;
        var _duration = _options.duration;
        var _switchTime = _options.switchTime;
        var _controlEvent = _options.event;
        var _currentNum = (_options.currentNum ? jQuery(_options.currentNum, _this) : false);
        var _allNum = (_options.allNum ? jQuery(_options.allNum, _this) : false);
        var _startSlide = _options.startSlide;
        var _noCycle = _options.noCircle;
        var _onChange = _options.onChange;
        var _pagerGener = _options.pagerGener;
        var _pagerHold = jQuery(_options.pagerHold,_this);
        var _caption = jQuery(_options.caption,_this);
        var _paging = '';
        if(_pagerGener){
            for(var i=0; i< _slides.length; i++){
                _paging += '<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li>';
            }
            _pagerHold.html('<ul>'+_paging+'</ul>');
        }
        var _pagerLinks = jQuery(_options.pagerLinks, _this);
        // gallery init
        var _hover = false;
        var _prevIndex = 0;
        var _currentIndex = 0;
        var _slideCount = _slides.length;
        var _timer;
        if(_slideCount < 2) return;

        _prevIndex = _slides.index(_slides.filter('.'+_activeClass));
        if(_prevIndex < 0) _prevIndex = _currentIndex = 0;
        else _currentIndex = _prevIndex;
        if(_startSlide != null) {
            if(_startSlide == 'random') _prevIndex = _currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*_slideCount);
            else _prevIndex = _currentIndex = parseInt(_startSlide);
        }
        _slides.hide().eq(_currentIndex).show();
        _caption.hide().eq(_currentIndex).show();
        if(_autoRotation) _this.removeClass(_pausedClass).addClass(_playClass);
        else _this.removeClass(_playClass).addClass(_pausedClass);

        // gallery control
        if(_btnPrev.length) {
            _btnPrev.bind(_controlEvent,function(){
                prevSlide();
                return false;
            });
        }
        if(_btnNext.length) {
            _btnNext.bind(_controlEvent,function(){
                nextSlide();
                return false;
            });
        }
        if(_pagerLinks.length) {
            _pagerLinks.each(function(_ind){
                jQuery(this).bind(_controlEvent,function(){
                    if(_currentIndex != _ind) {
                        _prevIndex = _currentIndex;
                        _currentIndex = _ind;
                        switchSlide();
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }

        // play pause section
        if(_btnPlayPause.length) {
            _btnPlayPause.bind(_controlEvent,function(){
                if(_this.hasClass(_pausedClass)) {
                    _this.removeClass(_pausedClass).addClass(_playClass);
                    _autoRotation = true;
                    autoSlide();
                } else {
                    _autoRotation = false;
                    if(_timer) clearTimeout(_timer);
                    _this.removeClass(_playClass).addClass(_pausedClass);
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
        if(_btnPlay.length) {
            _btnPlay.bind(_controlEvent,function(){
                _this.removeClass(_pausedClass).addClass(_playClass);
                _autoRotation = true;
                autoSlide();
                return false;
            });
        }
        if(_btnPause.length) {
            _btnPause.bind(_controlEvent,function(){
                _autoRotation = false;
                if(_timer) clearTimeout(_timer);
                _this.removeClass(_playClass).addClass(_pausedClass);
                return false;
            });
        }
        // gallery animation
        function prevSlide() {
            _prevIndex = _currentIndex;
            if(_currentIndex > 0) _currentIndex--;
            else {
                if(_noCycle) return;
                else _currentIndex = _slideCount-1;
            }
            switchSlide();
        }
        function nextSlide() {
            _prevIndex = _currentIndex;
            if(_currentIndex < _slideCount-1) _currentIndex++;
            else {
                if(_noCycle) return;
                else _currentIndex = 0;
            }
            switchSlide();
        }
        function refreshStatus() {
            if(_pagerLinks.length) _pagerLinks.removeClass(_activeClass).eq(_currentIndex).addClass(_activeClass);
            if(_currentNum) _currentNum.text(_currentIndex+1);
            if(_allNum) _allNum.text(_slideCount);
            _slides.eq(_prevIndex).removeClass(_activeClass);
            _slides.eq(_currentIndex).addClass(_activeClass);
            if(_noCycle) {
                if(_btnPrev.length) {
                    if(_currentIndex == 0) _btnPrev.addClass(_disabledClass);
                    else _btnPrev.removeClass(_disabledClass);
                }
                if(_btnNext.length) {
                    if(_currentIndex == _slideCount-1) _btnNext.addClass(_disabledClass);
                    else _btnNext.removeClass(_disabledClass);
                }
            }
            if(typeof _onChange === 'function') {
                _onChange(_this, _currentIndex);
            }
        }
        function switchSlide() {
            _slides.eq(_prevIndex).fadeOut(_duration);
            _slides.eq(_currentIndex).fadeIn(_duration);
            _caption.eq(_prevIndex).fadeOut();
            _caption.eq(_currentIndex).fadeIn();
            if(_autoHeight) _slides.eq(_currentIndex).parent().animate({height:_slides.eq(_currentIndex).outerHeight(true)},{duration:_duration,queue:true});
            refreshStatus();
            autoSlide();
        }

        // autoslide function
        function autoSlide() {
            if(!_autoRotation || _hover) return;
            if(_timer) clearTimeout(_timer);
            _timer = setTimeout(nextSlide,_switchTime+_duration);
        }
        if(_pauseOnHover) {
            _this.hover(function(){
                _hover = true;
                if(_timer) clearTimeout(_timer);
            },function(){
                _hover = false;
                autoSlide();
            });
        }
        refreshStatus();
        autoSlide();
    });
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can u provide link for sample html code using FadeGallery?